# What can I do to reduce the actuall app size of an android app?

Tags: android, apk, google-maps-android-api-2, android-proguard, android-storage

I'm currently developing an android app using the Google Maps Android API and therefore the Google Play Services.

The generated release APK (utilizing proguard) has about 20MB (depending on the target platform).

After installation the App Info from the Android settings show about 44MB. I know that the APK is compressed/zipped, but can you tell me why the installed app is so much bigger compared to the APK?

I'm not downloading any data with OBB files. And all data is stored in the internal storage.

Comment: add only required dependency.. not whole playservice...
and analyze apk through build option and remove unused resources...

Comment: I'm only adding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4`

Answer (score 0):

The application size increases mostly because of the large images and libraries. Therefore, you have two options:

1. Check your images and icons, and if needed, reduce their sizes. If you are using large png's, you can also reduce their sizes with:
   https://tinypng.com/
2. Reduce your dependencies. As I understood, you are adding whole play services, not only maps.

Instead, you can use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
```

Comment: I'm only using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'`- I also reduced my png files in my assets folder - my whole assets folder is about 9.6MB

Comment: 9.6MB is already too much, for a huge project that I am working on, we have only ~5MB for almost 500 files.
Plus, 10MB for libraries and code is also too much. You should check your libraries again and exclude the ones that are not needed.

Comment: hm - I'm storing some png tiles in my asset folder an offline map. Its about 1226 png files in total 6.4MB. The files are already compressed and only cover 4-bit-color max.

Comment: The problem might be, that I'm using the libjsqlite jniLib. Which is quite huge. But I already seperated the apk to the different platforms such the each platform get its own .so file.